# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - Can't find the error in my method

Tags: java, exception, arraylist, methods

I'm trying to figure out where I made mistakes in my code but I can't get out of it.

I'm writing a simple Hangman game code.
It seems to work until a wrong letter is typed in the JTextArea.
The error appears to be located in my "gioca()" method.

Here's my code:

```
package giocoimpiccato;

//Frame in cui si visualizza il gioco. Qui c'è il metodo main.

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

//Composto da 1 JLABEL per la foto, 1 JLABEL per il titolo, 1 JLABEL per il 
risultato, 1 JLABEL per le lettere inserite, 1 JLABEL per la parola e 1 
JTEXTAREA per inserire le lettere
public class GiocoImpiccatoFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame 
{
public String parolaDaIndovinare;
public ArrayList<String> lettereUsate; //uso un vettore perchè ha grandezza variabile
public int tentativi = 6;
public ArrayList<Integer> lettereTrovate;
public int sfondoCount = 0;
public ImageIcon[] sfondi; //uso un array perchè ha grandezza fissa
public int sfondoUsato = 0;
public String lettUsate = "";

//costruttore
public GiocoImpiccatoFrame() 
{
    lettereTrovate = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    lettereUsate = new ArrayList<String>();
    parolaDaIndovinare = leggiParola();
    sfondi =  new ImageIcon[sfondoCount + 1];
    for(int i=0; i<sfondoCount; i++)
    {
        ImageIcon file = new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/albero" + i + ".jpg"));
        sfondi[i] = file;
    }

    initComponents();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null); //per far apparire il frame in centro allo schermo

    labelSfondo.setIcon(sfondi[0]);
}

//metodo che estrae casualmente una parola dall'array
public String leggiParola()
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int idx = 0;
    String parola = "";

    String[] parole = new String[10];
    parole[0] = "cane";
    parole[1] = "gatto";
    parole[2] = "pescespada";
    parole[3] = "frutta";
    parole[4] = "videogioco";
    parole[5] = "sentinella";
    parole[6] = "oviparo";
    parole[7] = "ateneo";
    parole[8] = "poltrona";
    parole[9] = "fucina";

    idx = r.nextInt(parole.length - 1);
    parola = parole[idx];

    return parola;
}

//controlla le lettere inserite, le confronta con quelle della parola e le inserisce (tramite metodo visualizzazioneParola) e segna gli errori
public void gioca(String c)
{
    boolean fine = false;
    boolean nonUsato = true;
    boolean trovato = false;

    if (c.length() == 1)
    {
        for (String lettUsata : lettereUsate) //ciclo for che percorre tutto un array e assegna alla variabile lettUsata ogni volta un valore dell'array fino a farli tutti
        {
            if ((c.toUpperCase()).equals(lettUsata.toUpperCase())) // equals per le stringhe - toUpperCase trasforma tutto in maiuscole per il confronto
            {
                nonUsato = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (nonUsato)
        {
            lettereUsate.add(c);
            lettUsate = lettUsate + " " + c;
            trovato = cerca(c.charAt(0));
            if (trovato)
            {
                labelParola.setText(visualizzazioneParola());
                fine = haiVinto();
            }
            else
            {
                tentativi--;
                labelSfondo.setIcon(sfondi[++sfondoUsato]);
            }
        }
    }
}

//metodo che restituisce una variabile booleana dopo aver confrontato il carattere in ingresso con quelli della parola da indovinare
public boolean cerca(char c)
{
    boolean trovato = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < parolaDaIndovinare.length(); i++)
    {
        if (Character.toLowerCase(parolaDaIndovinare.charAt(i)) == Character.toLowerCase(c))
        {
            lettereTrovate.add(i);
            trovato = true;
        }
    }

    return trovato;
}

//metodo che restituisce una variabile booleana per la vittoria
public boolean haiVinto()
{
    if (parolaDaIndovinare.length() == lettereTrovate.size())
    {
        labelParola.setText(visualizzazioneParola());
        labelRisultato.setText("Hai Vinto!");
        txtInput.setEnabled(false);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

// inserisce le lettere alla posizione corretta o la lineetta in caso di lettera ancora da indovinare
public String visualizzazioneParola()
{
    String str = "";
    boolean trovato = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < parolaDaIndovinare.length(); i++)
    {
        trovato = false;

        for (int j : lettereTrovate)
        {
            if (j == i)
            {
                str = str + parolaDaIndovinare.charAt(i);
                trovato = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (trovato == false)
        {
            str = str + "_";
        }

        if (i != parolaDaIndovinare.length()-1)
        {
            str = str + " ";
        }
    }

    return str;
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    labelTitolo = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    labelLettere = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    labelParola = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    labelRisultato = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    txtInput = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    labelSfondo = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Il Gioco dell'Impiccato");
    setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1000, 600));
    setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1000, 600));
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    labelTitolo.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Copperplate Gothic Light", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
    labelTitolo.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
    labelTitolo.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    labelTitolo.setText("Il Gioco dell'Impiccato");
    getContentPane().add(labelTitolo);
    labelTitolo.setBounds(156, 6, 662, 94);

    labelLettere.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
    labelLettere.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
    labelLettere.setText(lettUsate);
    getContentPane().add(labelLettere);
    labelLettere.setBounds(6, 146, 470, 64);

    labelParola.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Copperplate Gothic Light", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
    labelParola.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
    labelParola.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    labelLettere.setText(visualizzazioneParola());

    labelLettere.setToolTipText(parolaDaIndovinare);
    getContentPane().add(labelParola);
    labelParola.setBounds(6, 410, 651, 78);

    labelRisultato.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Copperplate Gothic Light", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
    labelRisultato.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
    labelRisultato.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    getContentPane().add(labelRisultato);
    labelRisultato.setBounds(6, 506, 812, 88);

    txtInput.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
    txtInput.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
    txtInput.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);
    txtInput.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            txtInputActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(txtInput);
    txtInput.setBounds(6, 262, 142, 91);

    labelSfondo.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    getContentPane().add(labelSfondo);
    labelSfondo.setBounds(0, 0, 1000, 600);

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void txtInputActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    gioca(txtInput.getText());

    if(tentativi==0)
    {
        labelRisultato.setText("HAI PERSO: la parola era '" + parolaDaIndovinare.toUpperCase() + "'");
        txtInput.setEnabled(false);
    }

    txtInput.setText("");
    labelLettere.setText(lettUsate);
}                                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GiocoImpiccatoFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GiocoImpiccatoFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GiocoImpiccatoFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GiocoImpiccatoFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new GiocoImpiccatoFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel labelLettere;
private javax.swing.JLabel labelParola;
private javax.swing.JLabel labelRisultato;
private javax.swing.JLabel labelSfondo;
private javax.swing.JLabel labelTitolo;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtInput;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

And here's the exception it generates when I type a wrong letter:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at giocoimpiccato.GiocoImpiccatoFrame.gioca(GiocoImpiccatoFrame.java:97)
at giocoimpiccato.GiocoImpiccatoFrame.txtInputActionPerformed(GiocoImpiccatoFrame.java:240)
```

It's like the wrong letter can't be added to my ArrayList lettereUsate.

I'd appreciate a tip.
Thank you!

HERE'S LINE 97:

```
labelSfondo.setIcon(sfondi[++sfondoUsato]);
```

Comment: Which line is line 97?

Comment: Line 97 is where cerca() method starts

Comment: That is not possible. Please edit your question and show where line 97 is. Line 97 is indicated in your exception: `at giocoimpiccato.GiocoImpiccatoFrame.gioca(GiocoImpiccatoFrame.java:97)`

Comment: Yes, you were right, I'm sorry.
I edited my question adding at the end Line 97.
You were right, the exception is generated by the uncorrect use of my array.
May you help me to fix it?

Comment: Solved!
Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the `sfondi` array like this:

```
sfondi = new ImageIcon[sfondoCount + 1];
```

`sfondoCount` is set to 0 and never changed, so `sfondi` will always be a 1 element array (so the only valid index will be `sfondi[0]`). Later, you do this:

```
labelSfondo.setIcon(sfondi[++sfondoUsato]);
```

Before this statement is executed, `sfondoUsato` is `0` but because you are using the prefix increment, it will be incremented before its value is used, so you will end up with:

```
labelSfondo.setIcon(sfondi[1]);
```

And we've already determined that `sfondi[0]` is the only valid index.

Comment: So what would you suggest? I'd like to make JLabel Icon change whenever an error is done.